# What is the correct pronunciation of the name Ceri?

Tags: pronunciation

Is it incorrect to pronounce the name *Ceri* — which is of Welsh origin I think — as *seri* instead of *keri*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pronounced *KE-ri*. You can find the source [here](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Ceri).

Comment: yes, but would the pronunciation I suggested be incorrect?

Comment: @user: Personally, I've never heard it pronounced otherwise. Perhaps another member of the community has different experience. Wait and see.

Comment: @user It would be incorrect if it was meant to be a Welsh name. In Welsh the 'c' is always a hard 'k' sound. 'Celt' and 'Celtic' (as in race of people) should always be pronounced 'Kelt' and 'Keltic'. The exception is the Scottish football team Celtic which calls itself 'Seltic' for some reason.

Comment: If it's your own name, in the U.S. at least, you can pronounce it any way you want. Consider Colin Powell. The only drawback is that everybody else will mispronounce it and people might think you're weird.

Comment: Ironically, the audio link contradicts the written explanation and mechanically pronounces the name with a soft c, similar to the iPhone [**Siri**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKM5a8UIEnw), just goes to show how many users actually bother visiting links and checking stuff.

Comment: YouTube "Ceri Rees' audition" https://youtu.be/XqBKsjwwtqE?t=23s

Comment: Well, on a sample of 100% of the men I have known called Ceri, they all pronounced it 'Kerry'. (Okay there was just one of him, but he *was* welsh.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it would be wrong to pronounce it as *Seri*.

Think *Catherine* or *Callum*: you say the C like K.

*Ceri* is my name and as soon as I leave Wales people have trouble pronouncing it.
It’s pronounced the same as *Kerry*; it's just the Welsh Celtic spelling.

Comment: +1 mostly for being correct, but partially for being Welsh :-)

Comment: +1 Glad to see an answer from someone called Ceri. Remembering the word "Celtic" ( I always pronounce with 'k' ) helps avoid mispronouncing your name. Thx for dropping by Ceri.

Answer (score 2):

Names are pronounced as the owner wishes them to be; imagine how you would feel if somebody told you you were pronouncing your name 'wrongly'.
*Ceri* is of Welsh origin, and pronounced with a hard c in Welsh, so most Ceris use that pronunciation. But there is nothing to prevent a mother seeing the name in print and giving it to her daughter, pronounced with a soft c.

Comment: Exactly the point I wanted to make. +1

Comment: Isn't it a male name? The only Ceri I ever knew was a welsh bloke.

Answer (score 2):

My name is Ceri and I hate it when people pronounce my name with an S. I know that C and be said with an S sound, but it simple really. C for Cat. You never hear any one going Satherine, instead of Catherine. So why is it any different with Ceri?

Comment: So how would *you* pronounce "Cyril" and "Cecil" and "Cilla"? I could go on... Ceri is a Welsh name, and it has its own unique pronunciation rule, don't expect others to automatically know them.

Comment: And, if you go to Italy expect to be called *Cherry*.  Every language has its own pronunciation rules.  Ce at the front of a word is usually pronounced Se in English.  Ke would be pronounced the way you expect it to be pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

the name is of Welsh/Celtic origin and roughly translates to fair, blessed poetry. It is short for Ceridwen and is properly pronounced Keridwen.

That being said, my name is Ceridwyn, or Ceri for short. My mother liked the sound of a soft c as opposed to a hard c, so I've always been known as Seridwyn or Seri. Technically having "wyn" as opposed to "wen" is grammatically incorrect as well (WYN is masculine; WEN is feminine), but I quite like my name, as do others. People tend to like the sound of Seri; it sounds like a variant of Sara.

Note: Nobody is going to judge you if you like the name with a soft c ("s") [save for the Welsh], so say it however you want. Names should be fun!